# RESTful principles for "magic fields"

Tags: rest, api, idempotent

In a RESTful API backend for a mobile app client we have a resource, `User`, with the database field `birthday`.

When Sam is authenticated an request his own profile, `GET /user/1`, we receive a resource like this:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Sam Smith",
    birthday: "1990-01-01",
    age: 27
}
```

In this scenario, `age` is merely a convenience for the client, that won't have to calculate Sam's age.

But when a stranger requests Sam's profile, `GET /user/1`, he receives a slightly different resource:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Sam Smith",
    age: 27
}
```

Here, `birthday` is omitted for privacy, and now `age` is not just about convenience, it is needed, because it's not possible for the client to calculate age without the `birthday`.

**I am already instructing the client that some fields may be omitted depending on permissions.**

But when Sam wants to update his profile, he takes the resource he received before, alters it, and `PUT /user/1`.

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Sam Smith",
    birthday: "2000-02-02", // Birthday was changed
    age: 27 // Should he update the age? It's the same data source as birthday.
}
```

Server-side I could choose to ignore `age`, but a client might think they can alter the `age` field directly. I could forbid the `age` field on `PUT` resources, but then the client would have to modify resource schema that it received from the `GET` request.

What are best principles in a situation like this?

Should the client really calculate the new age in the `PUT` request, even though it will then be ignored by the server, otherwise returning a `HTTP 409` conflict response?

Comment: How about not to send `age` and name at all? 
Just send changed fields with ID, make a partial update. 

And make `PATCH` request.

Comment: In case of `PATCH` if user sends `age` in request, I see it reasonable to return an error.

Comment: @IoaneSharvadze I agree for the `PATCH` request, but would like to support `PUT` as well.

Comment: Pretty sure this is what you were looking for: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/208271/how-should-a-rest-api-handle-put-requests-to-partially-modifiable-resources. Hopefully anyone else who stumbles upon this will find a solution there.